SQS Visibility Issue while upgrading AWS Spring Cloud 2.x to 3.x - visibility.extend
As a part of upgrading AWS Spring Cloud to 3.x (along with AWS SDK to 2.x), I'm trying the following:
Change 
from
        visibility.extend(Number); 
to 
        visibility.changeTo(Number);

But, I'm getting the below error:
software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException: is not authorized to perform: sqs:changemessagevisibility

Commenting the above visibility line works as expected and messages are processed. Issue is just with visibility extension.
If you have any clue, please let me know.
Thanks!
Followed the documentation as per the link below
https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0-RC1/apidocs/io/awspring/cloud/sqs/listener/Visibility.html
But, it appears there are some changes between 2.x and 3.x of Spring Cloud with respect to permissions.
I'm not sure whether some other method / approach is available for this functionlity.

I'm able to resolve this error.
Resolution is, if it is Asynchronous SQS client (SqsAsyncClient), calling the below method has resolved the issue.
visibility.changeToAsync(seconds)

Import statement is:
import io.awspring.cloud.sqs.listener.Visibility

